# (Ruby/ Rails) undefined method when I'm trying to reference a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, methods, activeresource

So continuing on my adventure of active resource and active record I'm trying to do a simple get method within an active resource but everytime I try to reference the variable, It throws a method undefined exception. Perhaps Its better to explain it in code.

```
class UserRequest < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3008"


 def get_status 
    puts self.status
    return self.status
  end
```

The active record on the other side is made up of of URL, depth and status.

So i go through the console as one would,

```
?> @received = UserRequest.find(10)
=> #<UserRequest:0x101174e98 @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"user_request"=>#<UserRequest:0x10111ddc8 @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"created_at"=>Thu Jul 14 10:43:32 UTC 2011, "depth"=>583, "updated_at"=>Thu Jul 14 10:43:32 UTC 2011, "url"=>"www.mendi.com", "id"=>10, "status"=>"In queue: not started"}>}>
>> 
?> 
?> @received.get_status
NoMethodError: undefined method `status' for #<UserRequest:0x101174e98>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1401:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/shanemoore/Desktop/activeResourceTest/webApps/app/models/user_request.rb:17:in `get_status'
    from (irb):47
>>
```

it seems when I reference the .status part of an activerecord, Its looking for a method rather than the variable which I thought was brought back on the .find. The same issue happens on server side console.

2 definite possibilities is I'm referencing the variables wrong (although I've tried multiple different ways of calling it asides from self.whatever)

Or my concept of how classes are built in active record is wrong. (possibly this self.initialise I keep hearing about)

Anyone care to help?

Comment: If all your get_status method is doing is returning self.status, you can just access it directly through @received.status. No need to define a separate getter method

Comment: I don't see `status` attribute in your model. Did you do `rake db:migrate` after you added it?

Comment: For the moment all the get_status method is doing is responding witht he variable but after I'm finished, it will post the results as a json via net::http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand the purpose of the `get_status` method.
Being status an attribute, you don't need to define that method, Rails does that for you.
So `@received.status` should work just fine.

Comment: I just want to reference the variable for the moment. When its finished, I want it to respond with a json post request